# Breeze JS: Error on manager.fetchMetadata() after upgrading from 1.4.4 to 1.4.5 to support Entity Framework 6 model

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, entity-framework-6, hottowel

I just upgraded Breeze (client and server) from 1.4.4 to 1.4.5. 
When I switched over to point to the server where Breeze is upgraded (using Breeze 1.4.5, Entity Framework 6, Web Api 2, MVC 5), I had the following error when fetching the Metadata (manager.fetchMetadata()). This is the error message that I have:

> Metadata query failed for:
>   `http://localhost:50015/breeze/Application/Metadata`. Unable to either
>   parse or import metadata: Bad nav properties; [object Object]

If I point to the server that is based off of Breeze 1.4.4, Entity Framework 5, Web Api 1, MVC 4, my SPA doesn't break on manager.fetchMetadata(). It doesn't go the .fail promise.

Both Entity Framework models are pointing to the same database, they have the same entities and same data.

Was this bug introduced to Breeze 1.4.5 ?? Or did I miss a step during the upgrade process?? Basically I'm using exactly the same code in my breeze controller from 1.4.4, to 1.4.5. Also Breeze client was upgraded to 1.4.5.
If you need the Metadata, let me know and I can provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I debugged the function that fetches the metadata, and I found some client side entities that were defined with associations pointing to the old Entity Framework 5 namespaces. It was throwing the exception in CsdlMetadataParser.parse within Breeze. I corrected the namespaces and the issue was resolved.

Comment: What kind of associations?  I'm getting this error and it doesn't even get to CsdlMetadataparser.parse

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have no idea what you are running into. We converted most of the breeze samples to use Breeze 1.4.5 and WebApi 2/Entity Framework 6, so you might want to take a look at them.  This includes the DocCode and the ToDo/Angular samples (among others).  My guess is that something got missed during your upgrade.

I've found that removing all the relevant nuget packages first and then reinstalling then usually fixes these issues.

Please post back when you do figure this out, so that we can let others know.

Comment: I found the problem, I debugged the function that fetches the metadata, and I found some client side entities that were defined with associations pointing to the old Entity Framework 5 namespaces. It was throwing the exception in CsdlMetadataParser.parse within Breeze. I corrected the namespaces and the issue was resolved.